# I can't get the value of a input within a datalist?

Tags: javascript, html, input, html-datalist

I have a datalist box that looks like this:

```
<td>
    <input list="screens.screenid-datalist" type="text" id="screens.screenid" onblur="validate('0','0','jacques')">
    <datalist id="screens.screenid-datalist">
        <option value="Login"></option>
        <option value="ScreenCreator"></option>
    </datalist>
    <label id="val-screens.screenid" class="Label_Error" style="visibility: hidden;">*</label>
</td>
```

and I have a JavaScript code which has to get the value from this datalist.

I tried all the following things to get the value

```
document.getElementById('screens.screenid').value
document.getElementById('screens.screenid').text
document.getElementById('screens.screenid').innerHTML
document.getElementById('screens.screenid').option
```

and it just does not seem to work.

Is there something wrong with my JavaScript or with my HTML code?

when I use the console to get the value:
[image: when I use the console to get the value]

Comment: Works fine for me (see http://jsfiddle.net/Uz2ak/) - to select an item from the datalist in `type=text` input I have to start typing it and pick it from a menu, or press the down arrow, in Chrome 28.

Comment: `document.getElementById('screens.screenid').value` works for me too (Chrome 30, IE 10 and FF 22).

Comment: @Jacques can you provide more context to this code? Is it possible that your script is running before the DOM is ready, for example?

Comment: Do you want to get value from data-list or input??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Took sometime to figure this out. Look at my code below :

```js
function validate(){
    console.log(document.getElementById('screens.screenid').value); //WORKS

    console.log(document.getElementById('screens.screenid').text);
    console.log(document.getElementById('screens.screenid').innerHTML);
    console.log(document.getElementById('screens.screenid').option);

}
```

```html
<input list="screens.screenid-datalist" type="text" id="screens.screenid" onblur="validate('0','0','jacques')">
   <datalist id="screens.screenid-datalist">
   <option value="Login"></option>
   <option value="ScreenCreator"></option>
  </datalist>
<label id="val-screens.screenid" class="Label_Error" style="visibility: hidden;">*</label>
<a href='#' onclick="validate">validate</a>
```

Now the first one will get the `value` as expected, but the `text` `option` will not work for the obvious reason that you do not have text here. Also, `innerHTML` will get you the child html and not the value. Further more , you can't get `innerHTML` of an input list, but you can get it for the datalist.

Try this : `console.log(document.getElementById('screens.screenid-datalist').innerHTML);`

I tried it and got the `innerHTML` without any hassle :

```
<option value="Login"></option>
<option value="ScreenCreator"></option>
```

Find the bin here : http://jsbin.com/inigaj/1/edit

Comment: i added a screen shot of the console, for some reason it doesnt seem to work for me

Comment: @Jacques Is your input list formed dynamically ?

Comment: @Jacques : that's why it's not coming up, since console.log is happening before the list is formed. Try to induce javascript time out there to delay the console.log or give `Event.onDOMready`

Comment: how would i use the Event.onDOMready, is this the event that goes in my js function that returns a boolean value or is it an event on the html document?

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the `input` event on the `<input>` element and then compare the `<input>` element's value to all of the `<option>` values to isolate selection of an option (vs keying in values to the input).

```js
const input = document.getElementById("ice-cream-choice");
const list = document.getElementById("ice-cream-flavors");

input.addEventListener("input", function(e){
  if(isOptionValue(list,input.value)){
    console.log("List input fired: " + input.value);
  }
});
function isOptionValue(datalist,val){
  let result = false;
  if(datalist instanceof Element || datalist instanceof HTMLDocument){
    let options = datalist.querySelectorAll("option");
    options.forEach(function(option){
      if (option.value === val){
        result = true;
      }
    })
  }
  return result;
}
```

```html
<input list="ice-cream-flavors" id="ice-cream-choice" name="ice-cream-choice">

<datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">
    <option value="Chocolate">
    <option value="Coconut">
    <option value="Mint">
    <option value="Strawberry">
    <option value="Vanilla">
</datalist>
```